# Compiling OpenSC on Windows

Tags: pkcs#11, opensc

Context:

I am following the guide for the open source project OpenSC https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC to compile the solution on Windows and get the opensc-pkcs11.dll module to use it for communications (such as OpenSSH) with HSM's via PKCS#11 standard. Currently I am using the latest stable release 0.21.0 (msi installer) and it works perfectly. However when I use https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Compiling-on-Windows guide to compile the solution using Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt I can successfully build the libraries however the opensc-pkcs11.dll always returns pkcs11: 0x5: CKR_GENERAL_ERROR when I try to use it and I am not sure what am I missing here.

Setup:

1. git clone https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC.git
2. git checkout 30180986a08cf71fe4af4b50251a8bb5b1ab95af (0.21.0 commit for the right version)
3. Manually Creating Built Source Files
4. nmake /f Makefile.mak

Building it for x64, with x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019.

That should be it according to the guidelines as I do not need openpace/openssl/zlib to compile the opensc-pkcs11 as far as I understand.

Problem summary:

1. If I download from releases https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/releases version OpenSC-0.21.0 the compiled opensc-pkcs11.dll works as expected
2. If I compile it from source code based on v0.21.0 commit I get 0x5: CKR_GENERAL_ERROR when trying to use the library for e.g. OpenSSH, tested that this happens for other/previous commits as well, there for I suspect that I am missing something here.

Has anyone experienced the same issue? Maybe there is some build config anyone could share so I can understand what am I missing here?